# socket and multiprocessing blocking

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to write a program that utilizes sockets to talk to others in the cluster. the problem I am having is that I can not seam to implment a server without blocking on accept() even though I have tried to utilize threading and multiprocessing.

server.py

```
import traceback
import sys, base64
from threading import Thread
import time


def server(host="", port=65098):
    host= host
    port= port
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    soc.bind((host, port))
    soc.listen(5)
    clients = []
    time.sleep(1)
    while 1:
        try:
            clientsocket, clentaddr = soc.accept()
            clients.append(Thread(target=handler, args=(clientsocket, clientaddr)))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            soc.close()
        for cl in clients:
            if not cl.is_active:
                cl.join()
                clients.remove(cl)

def handler(clientsocket, clientaddr):
    while True:
        data = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
        if data.startswith('---'):
            if data[0:9] == '---test---':
                ping(clientsocket, data[10:])
        break
    clientsocket.close()

def ping(clientsocket, data):
    name = base64.decode(data)
    clientsocket.send(base64.encode(b'hi' + name))
```

then I move on to a test.py where I try to work on the noneblocking server with a test.

test.py

```
from lib import server
import pdb

thread1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=server.server())
pdb.set_trace()
thread1.daemon = True
thread1.start()
# pdb.set_trace()
import socket
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
pdb.set_trace()
soc.connect('localhost', 65098)
message = b'This is our message. It is very long but will only be transmitted in chunks of 16 at a time'
sock.sendall(message)
```

when I run test.py The program blocks. when I ctl+c it seams that the program is not advancing past line 5(test.py) and is blocking even though I have yet to call thread1.start as you can see I have a pdb trace. this is not being executed. I didn't think it should matter with threading but server.py in the stack seams to be on line 18 where it calls soc.accept().

This is strange behavior to me. any ideas?

Comment: What is `server.server()`?

Comment: `accept()` will block until a client connects. Why did you expect otherwise? And what makes you think your server is nonblocking? it isn't.

Comment: I expect it not to block because test.py calls it under mutiprocessing or threading. It should be under a separate thread that should allow test.py to continue. server.server() is the function under the server module.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin thanks for your question. server is both a imported module and a function in server so you have to call server.server() after importing it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it being inside a module is not allowing threading to run it without the second thread blocking the first thread. I was able to get around this by creating a function in tests.py called tcpserv all it dose is call server.server() instead of calling it directly as the multiprocessing target. test.py now looks like this and dumps to the debugger like I expect.

```
import multiprocessing
from lib import server
import pdb

def tcpserv():
    server.server()
thread1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=tcpserv)
thread1.start()
pdb.set_trace()
```